# No puedo cambiar el background de mi aplicación

Tags: ionic

Tengo un problema con cambiar el fondo de mi aplicación, lo hago llamando desde mi home.html con una clase y en mi css lo hago con background-color , pero no me deja cambiarlo, inspeccionó el elemento desde Google Chrome y veo que un archivo de style tiene activado un fondo blanco , lo desactivo y ya sale el color que declaró, pero no puedo encontrar ese archivo en mi proyecto, no sé qué hacer , espero me puedan ayudar y gracias

Comment: has probado poniendo  `background-color : #tucolor !important`? Si eso funcionara descartariamos otro tipo de incompatibilidades y despues buscariamos la manera de referenciar el elemento para que se aplique el color sin usar important, utilizando la especificidad del elemento.

Comment: Debes añadir algo más de información: ¿qué archivo es el que está sobre escribiendo tus estilos? ¿Cuál es tu código? La descripción del problema está clara, pero sin poder ver el error o el código, lo más que vamos a poder hacer es darte recomendaciones genéricas que pueden servirte (o no). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Ios6b si ya probé ese código y tampoco funciona :(

Answer (score 0):

tengo mi home.page.html

<-ion-content padding class="tapiz"->
<-img src="assets/icon/hollow.gif"->
<-/ion-content->

tengo mi home.page.scss

page-home{
}
.titulo{
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.tapiz{
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}

el estilo de titulo si lo agarra bien pero el background no

Answer (score 0):

```css
page-home{

}

.titulo{
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.tapiz{
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      <img src="assets/icon/logo.png" width="130">
      <p class="titulo">texto</p>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="tapiz">

</ion-content>
```

les dejo mi home.page.html y mi home.page.css, el estilo del titulo si lo agarra bien pero el de backgound no